# bash script: wildcard expression is not processed as expected

Tags: bash, for-loop, wildcard

In my bash script running on an ubuntu machine I have the following simple loop

```
for f in ~/logs/*.log
do
    echo "processing $f"
done
```

If there are files in the directory `~/logs` matching the pattern, it works as expected, i.e. I get

```
processing /home/foo/logs/a.log
processing /home/foo/logs/foo.log
processing /home/foo/logs/3.log
```

But when the dir is empty it treats `~/logs/*.log` as the only item to iterate over, so I get this

```
processing /home/foo/logs/*.log
```

How do I change this so that in this case it produces an empty iteration list and so never enters the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Two ways:**

Either, you can set the [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) shell option:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in ~/logs/*.log
do
    echo "processing $f"
done
```

or [test](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) for the existence of a file:

```
for f in ~/logs/*.log
do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
    echo "processing $f"
done
```